# in java socket programing, how to receive all incoming messages

Tags: java, websocket, socket.io

i want to receive all incoming messages(tcp,udp) in my java application. But this application should not based on port.ie, this application should receive all incoming tcp and udp requests.

Comment: you can't have udp or tcp without ports. you can't just slap some data on the wire and say "google.com via tcp, GO!". you MUST specify a port.

Comment: at least at the server end, ports are mandatory. By specifying that server's alloted port at all of your potential clients and directing messages to your server, you can receive all incoming messages at your server, as well as track those messages' source.

Comment: The OP only mentions receiving, not sending; in effect he's asking for a Java alternative to Wireshark (opening an ethernet socket in promiscuous mode). This is not possible in Java, at least not without JNI code.

Comment: or is there any other way to receive http and non http requests(udp ,.. etc) in java